# access database string criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

when using sql in access database, for string criteria, is it case sensitive? e.g. where PersonName like "LINDA", is equal to: where PersonName like "linda"?

Comment: Review https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-case-sensitive/. If you want case sensitivity, that requires some adjustments.

Comment: ISO SQL is case-insensitive by default, that includes MS Access, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, IBM Db2, etc. You need to opt-in to case-sensitive comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [StrComp](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/office/strcomp-funktion-strvgl-a9a4531e-3b2a-4218-b139-f7442bc10b96) function in an Access query

```
SELECT tblSource.ID, tblSource.Test
FROM tblSource
WHERE (((StrComp([tblSource].[Test],"LINDA",0))=0));
```

This will return only the rows with LINDA, it will not return Linda or LInda etc.